# how to groupBy and map at same transform on dataweave 2?

Tags: mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have this `dataweave 1.0 script` that works well:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flowVars.worklogs groupBy $.author.accountId map {
    accountId: $.author.accountId[0],
    displayName: $.author.displayName[0],
    timeSpentMinutesMonth: (sum $.timeSpentSeconds) / 3600,
    billableMinutesMonth: (sum $.billableSeconds) / 3600,
    emailAddress: ''
}
```

However, now I am updating the code for `mule 4`, and I couldn't make this transformation goes well.

I already tried to update it like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
vars.worklogs groupBy $.author.accountId map {
    accountId: $.author.accountId[0],
    displayName: $.author.displayName[0],
    timeSpentMinutesMonth: (sum($.timeSpentSeconds)) / 3600,
    billableMinutesMonth: (sum($.billableSeconds)) / 3600,
    emailAddress: ''
}
```

But I got this error:

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.ErrorBuilder$ErrorImplementation
{
  description="You called the function 'map' with these arguments: 
  1: Object ({"5d8b681427fe990dc2d3404a": [{self: "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/54...)
  2: Function ((v:Any, i:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: Array
  2: Function


 4| vars.worklogs groupBy $.author.accountId map (v, i) -> {
  |  ...
10| }

Trace:
  at map (line: 4, column: 1)
  at main (line: 4, column: 42)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
vars.worklogs groupBy $.author.accountId map (v, i) -> {
    accountId: v.author.accountId[0],
    displayName: v.author.displayName[0],
    timeSpentMinutesMonth: (sum(v.timeSpentSeconds)) / 3600,
    billableMinutesMonth: (sum(v.billableSeconds)) / 3600,
    emailAddress: ''
}".
```

The variable `worklogs` contains a `json`:

```
[
  {
    "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5408",
    "tempoWorklogId": 5408,
    "jiraWorklogId": 15408,
    "issue": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/ABC-123",
      "key": "ABC-123",
      "id": 11005
    },
    "timeSpentSeconds": 28800,
    "billableSeconds": 28800,
    "startDate": "2020-01-31",
    "startTime": "00:00:00",
    "description": "creating new song",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-28T13:30:58Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-28T13:30:58Z",
    "author": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=5d8b681427fe990dc2d3404a",
      "accountId": "5d8b681427fe990dc2d3404a",
      "displayName": "john lennon"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5408/work-attribute-values",
      "values": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5166",
    "tempoWorklogId": 5166,
    "jiraWorklogId": 15166,
    "issue": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CDE-99",
      "key": "CDE-99",
      "id": 10106
    },
    "timeSpentSeconds": 3600,
    "billableSeconds": 3600,
    "startDate": "2020-01-31",
    "startTime": "00:00:00",
    "description": "call with stakeholders",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-10T18:30:03Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-10T18:30:03Z",
    "author": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=5b27ad3902cfea1ba6411c3f",
      "accountId": "5b27ad3902cfea1ba6411c3f",
      "displayName": "chandler bing"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5166/work-attribute-values",
      "values": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5165",
    "tempoWorklogId": 5165,
    "jiraWorklogId": 15165,
    "issue": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CDE-99",
      "key": "CDE-99",
      "id": 10081
    },
    "timeSpentSeconds": 3600,
    "billableSeconds": 3600,
    "startDate": "2020-01-31",
    "startTime": "00:00:00",
    "description": "planning tulsa work trip",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-10T18:29:30Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-10T18:29:30Z",
    "author": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=5b27ad3902cfea1ba6411c3f",
      "accountId": "5b27ad3902cfea1ba6411c3f",
      "displayName": "chandler bing"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5165/work-attribute-values",
      "values": [
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5164",
    "tempoWorklogId": 5164,
    "jiraWorklogId": 15164,
    "issue": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/CDE-99",
      "key": "CDE-99",
      "id": 10108
    },
    "timeSpentSeconds": 7200,
    "billableSeconds": 7200,
    "startDate": "2020-01-31",
    "startTime": "00:00:00",
    "description": "exporting data to cd-rom",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-10T18:29:08Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-10T18:29:47Z",
    "author": {
      "self": "https://xpto.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?accountId=5b27ad3902cfea1ba6411c3f",
      "accountId": "5b27ad3902cfea1ba6411c3f",
      "displayName": "chandler-bing"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "self": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/5164/work-attribute-values",
      "values": [
        
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I don't understanding why this isn't working. I read the docs and found out that `groupBy` and `map` in `dw 2.0` works pretty much the same as `dw 1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004mXWvHSAW/how-do-i-group-and-map-an-array-of-objects) question, it is necessary to add a `pluck` after `groupBy`, and not add `map`:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
vars.worklogs groupBy $.author.accountId pluck {
    accountId: $.author.accountId[0],
    displayName: $.author.displayName[0],
    timeSpentMinutesMonth: (sum($.timeSpentSeconds)) / 3600,
    billableMinutesMonth: (sum($.billableSeconds)) / 3600,
    emailAddress: ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [in DataWeave 1.0 map() accepted an object as an argument](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-operators#using-map-on-an-object), in addition to arrays. In [DataWeave 2.0 it is defined only for arrays and null](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-map). You need to iterate over the keys in the result object of groubBy().

Comment: thanks for your answer, it explains why what i answered here works